# Domain points to Dynamic Ip for FTP server

Tags: dynamic, ftp, dns

I have setup filezilla server on my computer, and i would like to access it via ftp over the internet.

I have a domain name in place already (example: myftpsite.com) i would like this to point to the ftp server, but i do not have a static ip. I know that static ips are much better since you dont have to worry about changing the dynamic every few weeks or months. But i still dont want to use them.

I do not want to use dyndns or any other dns software. I know this can be done without it i just cant figure out how.

Thanks,
Zac

Comment: This site is for programming questions. Server configuration/networking is offtopic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alternative to dyndns is you can update your DNS records every time your IP changes manually, or make your own program/script that does so.

dyndns is just a program that does this automatically. It updates your name servers every time your IP changes.

The manual alternative would be to type your IP address into your DNS provider whenever it changes.

There isn't another way to do it, thats just how DNS works.